# What's happening with the Sword of Kas in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, lore

I can find some info about the sword and the fight with Kas and Vecna.

But where is Kas' Sword these days? Is there any official information about it?

Who got it after the fight? Where did it get lost after Kas died? Who holds the sword these days?

Answer (score 11):

## There's no Greyhawk material yet for 5E

Unfortunately, no material for any setting except the Forgotten Realms "officially" exists yet for 5E.

However you do have a few options:

1. *Vecna Lives*: This AD&D 2E adventure could be updated for 5th edition (though I'm not sure how much work it would take, I haven't looked at it for a while). It does provide a little blurb about the history of the sword, and if I remember it right, the players do encounter the sword.
2. *Book of Artifacts*: While this supplement (I think also for AD&D 2E) contains a page and picture of the Sword of Kas, it doesn't really provide much about where the sword is *now*, even for the time period of 2E. However, it provides some good suggestions on how to use it.

TL;DR: There really isn't a lot of history on what the Sword of Kas is doing currently. It seems that the official publishers have included it in a few books, but they really want DMs to decide where it is and why, as is the nature of most artifacts. They are powerful items with legendary histories, but most of them are fairly easy to incorporate into your own campaign. There's no real answer for where the sword is in the c. 1490s DR (5E timeframe, probably).

Answer (score 10):

The Sword of Kas is in the Dungeon Master's Guide, page 226.

Specific details of in-game history are up to the DM to decide.

Comment: I dont agree, those part of th history is publish some times as a history. Those are not simples NPCs ! But as im looking for there is nothing official.

But no, "Specific details of in-game history are up to the DM to decide" some times if you are playing in premade cenario you got to follow up the track... that why you use it.

Comment: Maybe mention that there is no official Greyhawk setting material at all for 5e (yet?), as that supports the point that 5e-specific event details are not available?